# PHP how to shorten XML file based on data?

Tags: php, xml

I have incoming XML file with specifications for product. It is structured like this:

```
<Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>3</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Panel</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;IPS-ADS&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>true</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>3133</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>4</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Maksimalna rezolucija</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;1920x1080&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>true</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>50</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>5</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Svjetlina</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;250&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>true</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>45</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>6</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Kontrast</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;0&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>false</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>46</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>7</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Vidljivi kut (hor.)</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;178&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>false</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>47</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0001137445</ProductCode>
    <Group>Osnovne karakteristike</Group>
    <ItemNo>8</ItemNo>
    <ItemName>Vidljivi kut (ver.)</ItemName>
    <ItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;178&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</ItemValues>
    <ForFilter>false</ForFilter>
    <ItemId>48</ItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0704935</ProductCode>
    <SpecificationGroup>Ostale karakteristike</SpecificationGroup>
    <SpecificationItemNo>3</SpecificationItemNo>
    <SpecificationItemName>Brzina čitanja</SpecificationItemName>
    <SpecificationItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;95&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</SpecificationItemValues>
    <SpecificationForFilter>false</SpecificationForFilter>
    <SpecificationItemId>307</SpecificationItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0704935</ProductCode>
    <SpecificationGroup>Ostale karakteristike</SpecificationGroup>
    <SpecificationItemNo>4</SpecificationItemNo>
    <SpecificationItemName>Brzina pisanja</SpecificationItemName>
    <SpecificationItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;45&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</SpecificationItemValues>
    <SpecificationForFilter>false</SpecificationForFilter>
    <SpecificationItemId>308</SpecificationItemId>
  </Table>
```

You can see that for 1 product with code `0001137445` there are 6 `<Table>` nodes and for product with code `0704935` there are 2 `<Table>` nodes.

I need check each `<Table><ProductCode>` like this:

```
if <Table><ProductCode> == ProductCodeFromDb
  copy <Table> and all children nodes
```

**- this "IF" is where I need help on how to do this?**

For instance - in my DB I have product with code `0704935` and after my that I should get the same XML file but without data about products I don't need so it would like this:

```
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0704935</ProductCode>
    <SpecificationGroup>Ostale karakteristike</SpecificationGroup>
    <SpecificationItemNo>3</SpecificationItemNo>
    <SpecificationItemName>Brzina čitanja</SpecificationItemName>
    <SpecificationItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;95&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</SpecificationItemValues>
    <SpecificationForFilter>false</SpecificationForFilter>
    <SpecificationItemId>307</SpecificationItemId>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ProductCode>0704935</ProductCode>
    <SpecificationGroup>Ostale karakteristike</SpecificationGroup>
    <SpecificationItemNo>4</SpecificationItemNo>
    <SpecificationItemName>Brzina pisanja</SpecificationItemName>
    <SpecificationItemValues>&lt;Values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt;Value&gt;45&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;</SpecificationItemValues>
    <SpecificationForFilter>false</SpecificationForFilter>
    <SpecificationItemId>308</SpecificationItemId>
  </Table>
```

I am trying to this without "save all data to DB and then do your magic" but I am not sure:

1. Is it possible
2. Is it better than "save to DB first"

XML file is about 50Mb with 76232 `<Table>` nodes and this should be done roughly within 1-2 hours.

What would be your suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: 1 to 2 hours processing time, or time until you need to have a working solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: With that large of a data set, I would opt for save to DB first.  XML is not really good for handling data sets that large.  If you dump that data into any sort of SQL database, you could query the kind of information you are looking for in a fraction of a second.

Comment: How does PHP or "DB" enter the mix, I only see some XML and no attempt.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly needs to be done. In any case, you can process your XML file via XSLT.

Comment: Not really sure if you're asking about how to structure your program from a performance perspective, or if you're looking for an overall attempt at filtering the XML.